# Comfortable Program Execution in Batch File based on pattern matching as a one liner

Tags: batch-file

I often run into the use case where I get a package from another source in an automated fashion (like nuget install)

On a common root I want to execute the target program but I do not have the exact path. I assume there is an easy way to get to execute something like that, ideally based on regex.

What I write right now is:

```
REM Example Paths:
REM packages\MyTool.1.0.0\tools\MyTool.exe
REM packages\MyTool.1.1.0.beta0001\tools\MyTool.exe
REM packages\MyTool\MyTool.exe

pushd packages
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('dir MyTool.exe /s /N /B') do set "MyToolEXE=%%A"
popd

call %MyToolEXE% parameter
```

what I would like to write is

```
call packages\.*\MyTool.exe parameter
```

Is there some way to get rid of that for statement and make the call happen as a one liner?

EDIT:

If the program has no parameters a possible one liner would be:

```
where MyTool.exe /R packages /F | cmd
```

this however is a corner case since usually parameters are required.

EDIT:

As Stephen pointed out in the comments, if the working directory is not an issue and details about the path are known pattern matching can be used in `pushd` so another one liner could be:

```
pushd packages\MyTool*\tools & MyTool.exe parameter & popd
```

this however changes the working directory which may be an issue if the parameters are relative paths for example.

Comment: @Squashman I think you are exactly right. Somehow I need to find the exe and then pipe it into decorating with parameters and then pipe that into cmd I think. I am just hoping someone did that in the past. It is a super common usecase for me so I think this may become a batch idiom at some point. If so I want it to be called the Match Execution Idiom.

Comment: how about `pushd packages\MyTool*` - `call MyTool.exe parameter` - `popd`? (assuming, there is just one subfolder starting with `MyTool`, otherwise, it will just take you to the first one)

Comment: @Stephan yeah, that would work if the working directory is not relevant. Otherwise the push would change that.

Comment: Another option, _limited to either having only a single instance of `MyTool.exe`, or executing every instance_, is to use `ForFiles`, i.e. `@ForFiles /P "packages" /S /M "MyTool.exe" /C "Cmd /C Start \"\" @path parameter`. _(obviously you can change `/C` to `/K` or try methods other than the `Start` command as necessary)_.

Comment: @Compo ForFiles seems really powerful and may be exactly what I need. I will check that later today, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User @Compo delivered this solution for a one liner that hits all requirements:

```
ForFiles /P packages /M "MyTool.exe" /S /C "cmd /c @path parameter"
```

This neatly fits into one line, executes on the work space and accepts parameters.

I hereby decree this to be the 'Compo Match Execution Idiom' for batch files.

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off &:: callme.bat location regex args
setlocal
pushd "%~1"
set "Mt="
REM find newest %2
for /f "tokens=*" %%? in ('dir /b /a-d /s /o-d /t:w "%~nx2" ^|findstr /i /r /c:"%~2"') do if not defined Mt set "Mt=%%~?"
popd
if defined Mt call %Mt% %~3
endlocal
```

Put it in one of %PATH% location

Comment: I love your solution but I need to run these one liners on remote machines where I can not install this path first. I love it none the less :)